# Is it possible to autocomplete all fields of a form that is divided into different steps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, autocomplete

I have a form that is divided into different steps/pages, but I'd like to autocomplete all fields when I select this option in the first field in the first step. For example, I have 3 different pages: first and last name, email address and phone number and all of them are wrapped inside the same form tag and each input contains the correct autocomplete property. But when I click to autofill (browser's suggestion) the first name, it works for the last name because they are in the same page, but it doesn't work for the other fields (email and phone number) because they are in different pages/steps in the process. For them, I have to click in the field and (again) in the browser's suggestion.

So, is it possible to fill all fields using the autocomplete feature when I have different steps in my form?

I've searched a lot, but I haven't found any solution.

A small example of this type of form:

```
<form onSubmit={submit}>
    {step === NAME && (
    <>
        <InputBox
            isRequired
            name="firstName"
            autoComplete="given-name"
            label="First name"
            onBlur={onInputBlur}
            onChange={onInputChange}
            value={firstName}
        />
        <InputBox
            isRequired
            name="lastName"
            autoComplete="family-name"
            label="Last name"
            onBlur={onInputBlur}
            onChange={onInputChange}
            value={lastName}
        />
        <Button type="button" onClick={() => this.setState({step: EMAIL})}>
            Next
        </Button>
    </>
    )}
    {step === EMAIL && (
    <>
        <InputBox
            isRequired
            name="email"
            autoComplete="email"
            label="Email"
            onBlur={onInputBlur}
            onChange={onInputChange}
            value={email}
        />
        <Button type="button" onClick={() => this.setState({step: PHONE})}>
            Next
        </Button>
    </>
    )}
    {step === PHONE && (
    <>
        <InputBox
            isRequired
            name="phoneNumber"
            autoComplete="tel"
            label="Phone number"
            onBlur={onInputBlur}
            onChange={onInputChange}
            value={phoneNumber}
        />
        <Button type="submit">
            Submit
        </Button>
    </>
    )}
</form>
```